# ScriptLab message error randomly

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

I randomly get this error in the console of then 'Running' pane of my Excel 2016 when using ScriptLab:

```js
[
   "Script error.",
   "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js", 
   0, 
   0, 
   undefined
]
```

This console error message appears not immediately after 'deploying' my project, but a few seconds later.

My project runs normally with no console errors and works as expected, tough.

Is this a bug?

---

EDIT: I was able to create a very small YAML snippet that shows the problem. Try running this example. I figured out that if you uncomment the line Office.initialize, the error doesn't happen anymore.

```
name: Test
description: Reproduce bug
author: FelipeCostaGualberto
host: EXCEL
api_set: {}
script:
    content: |-
        //Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $(function () {
                console.log("Test");
            });
        //};
    language: typescript
template:
    content: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n\t<script src=\"https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n</head>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>"
    language: html
style:
    content: ''
    language: css
libraries: |
    core-js@2.4.1/client/core.min.js
    @types/core-js

    jquery@3.1.1
    @types/jquery
```

Comment: Does this happen with *all* snippets (incl. the sample ones), or with just a particular one?  If it's just a particular one, feel free to share the code (and to file it as a bug on https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues)

Comment: I put an example YAML showing the issue in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Script Lab, you don't need a full HTML or an `Office.initialized`.  That's the beauty of it!  You can focus on just the relevant code, which essentially is just `console.log("test")` in your case, and an empty HTML.  (For a more real use-case, you might have a button defined in the HTML, and a click-handler with some sort of API manipulation in the JS).

Note that you need to have the Office.js reference as part of the libraries tab.

Take a look at some of the other Script Lab samples (or even the basic "new snippet" sample) to see what it could look like.

Comment: Thanks, that must be that. There is a reason I use full HTML structure in my Script Lab projects: convenience. I'm using Atom to build UI, Script Lab for the Excel part, and then VS to deploy. I set up my projects in a way I can just copy and paste between them so it will work in all plataforms. `Office.initialized` solved my issue, tough.